# Does kernel package version 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 fix CVE-2017-16939?

Tags: rhel, kernel, security

I know that in order to fix CVE-2017-16939 we need to install patch version 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7 as shown in https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2018:1318.

We currently have 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 installed in the server.

But Red Hat does not list the above CVE on their list of fixes in version 3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhsa-announce/2018-August/msg00006.html

I'm wondering whether to downgrade to package version 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7 or to keep both installed; or does 862.11.6.el7.x86_64 fix the above CVE?

Answer (score 2):

3.10.0-862.11.6.el7 is newer than 3.10.0-862.2.3.el7, and includes the fixes shipped in the latter version. So you don’t need to downgrade (and shouldn’t).

Comment: Further, you may want to try `rpm -q --changelog` against the RPM,  and grep for the CVE ref.